# Unbiased Estimator of $\sigma^4$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

> $\{X_i\}_1^n$ is random sample from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with unknown parameters. Find an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^4$.

My first thought was to estimate kurtosis (as it has $\sigma^4$ term) and the kurtosis of the normal distribution is known to be 3. For example, something like:
$$T = \frac{\sum_1^n (X_i - \bar{X})^4}{3n}$$

But I am unsure about the validity of above statistic and cannot determine whether it is biased or unbiased.

Also how do you go about finding an unbiased estimator? Perhaps you can use maximum likelihood or the method of moments to find an estimator and then check its unbiasedness.

What if they all are biased?

#### Edit:

I changed my statistic to be dependent on n, as per the comment below.

#### Edit 2:

One of my classmates used the following approach: 
$$\mathbb E\left[s^4\right] = \mathbb V\left[s^2\right] + \mathbb E\left[s^2\right]^2 = \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1} + \sigma^4 $$

To finally get: 
$$\mathbb E\left[\frac{(n-1)s^4}{n+1}\right] = \sigma^4$$
Here $s^2$ is $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)^2$


Is this also correct? If so what does it say about an umvue statistic.

Comment: The expectation of this statistic is unbounded. You should probably change the $3$ to something that is depend on $n$

Comment: Okay, i see the unbounded part, so would 3n do?

Comment: Probably something that is similar to $n$.

Comment: Well, that kind of is the gist of my problem in the first place, i.e., how to approach formulating such an estimator. Please bear with me, I am a beginner.

Comment: No problem. Can you start by computing the $\mathbb E\left[\left(X_i - \overline{X}\right)^4\right]$

Comment: I just used binomial expansion to get some terms i dont know how to deal with. What is $E[ \bar{X} ]$, i think you cant treat $\bar{X}$ as a constant and use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Let me add an answer with some hints.

Comment: The approach using $S^2$ is correct. However, you have small mistakes in the definition of $S^2$ you should probably divided by $n-1$ and in your final result should be another power of $2$.

Comment: Can you write now the final statistic?

Comment: Uhmm, dint you write it in your answer.

Comment: No using $S^2$ it will lead to another one.

Comment: Oh yeah i can manage that

Comment: I edit my answer to include the estimator as well. I am not sure but I think that the estimator that you find without using $S^2$ is better (has a smaller variance) than the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start by computing the $\mathbb E\left[\left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4\right]$. To be able to do that, we need to find the distribution of $X_i - \overline X$. This is not complicated since $X_i$ are normal distributed,

$$X_i - \overline X \sim \mathcal N\left(0, \left(1 - \frac1n\right)\sigma^2\right)$$

So $$\mathbb E\left[\left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4\right] = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\sigma^4 \mathbb E\left[Z^4\right] = 3\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\sigma^4$$

Now replace the true expectation by it empirical equivalent and $\sigma^4$ by its estimator (this is called **Moment Method** and it leads to an unbiased estimator)

$$\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4 = 3\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2} \widehat{\sigma^4}$$

So if you want to have an unbiased estimator, you can take:

$$\widehat{\sigma^4} = \frac{n}{3\left(n-1\right)^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4$$

---

Using $S^2$: as mentioned in the question $$\mathbb E\left[\frac{n-1}{n+1}S^4 \right] = \sigma^4$$ which leads to the following unbiased estimator:

$$\widehat{\sigma^4} = \frac{1}{n^2-1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^2\right)^2$$

Comment: Well, i completely spaced out on finding the distribution of $X_i - \bar{X}$ in the first place. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to ask if you think something is missing.

Comment: Okay so, one of my classmate arrived at $\frac{(n-1)\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n+1}$ as an unbiased estimator. This was done by using chi squared distribution and the identity $E[s^4] = Var[s^2] + E[s^2]^2$. Is it also correct, then it implies one is not umvue.

Comment: Yeah there was, i edited the original question to include this.

Comment: Since both your  $\widehat{\sigma^4}$ estimators are unbiased, any convex combination   of them is also unbiased.  It might be interesting to know which has a minimum variance